# Can't access variable from another C# script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working a unity 3d game and I've ran into a problem:

I have two boxes called `breakableBox` and `breakableBox_2`.
When the player collides with them, they add to the player's score variable `playerScore` and the box hides itself. Here's the code that both of the boxes use:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int playerScore;

    public Renderer rend;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.enabled = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        rend.enabled = false;
        playerScore++;
    }



}
```

And then in order to show the score, I have this script attached to the player camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Points : MonoBehaviour {
    int score = ExampleClass.playerScore;
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
        style.fontSize = 24;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(1, 1, 150, 30), score.ToString() + " points", style);
    }
}
```

However, the score stays at zero, even when in the console I can see that it added the points to the variable. If anyone knows how to help me fix this, that would be great.

Comment: It would probably be better practice to maybe set up your score change as an event. So you can just have your different scripts subscribe to that event that way the score only gets updated when it is changed.

Comment: Stop using OnGui and use [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the `score` int in your Points class, try this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Points : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnGUI()
    {
        int score = ExampleClass.playerScore;
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
        style.fontSize = 24;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(1, 1, 150, 30), score.ToString() + " points", style);
    }
}
```

Edit: as @MXD mentioned in the comment, it's better to not update values in `OnGUI` and do it in `Update()` Instead [or `FixedUpdate()` since your score system is physics reliant].

Comment: Performance wise it may be better to call it in an update instead of an OnGUI. As the OnGUI is called significantly more then an update.

Comment: @MXD yeah, also he'd better not store the score the way he does, but I'm just answering his specific question with the least amount of code :D
I upvoted your comment

Comment: It never hurts to give good advice along side good answers ;)

Comment: To be more precise: He/She should be using the ui system and not the immediate mode gui.